# Display Error Message from Private Method (Rails 6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method, `create`, which calls a private method `get_title`:

```rb
def create

  @article = @user.articles.new(article_params)
  @article.title = get_title(@article.link)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to user_path, success: "Article Saved."
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "Failed to save article."
  end

end
```

The `get_title` method works so long as there are no errors in the get request:

```rb
def get_title(url)
  request = HTTParty.get(url)
  document = Nokogiri::HTML(request.body)
  title = document.at_css "title"
  return title.text
end
```

I can catch the error with a begin/rescue before the Nokogiri call:

```rb
begin
  HTTParty.get(url)
rescue HTTParty::Error
  ...
rescue StandardError
  ...
else
  request = HTTParty.get(url)
end
```

I don't know how to stop the method and return the error to the `create` method.

How do I return an error from the rescue statement to the `create` method and display that error message in a `flash`?

Comment: Note, you don't need the explicit `return` at the end of the method. You can just do `title.text`.

Comment: Don't catch the error in get_title, let it bubble up and catch it in the create method.

Comment: Do you want `get_title` to just return something like `nil` or `false` if the operation failed? There's a lot going on in there that could blow up on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is "harden" this method so it doesn't explode unless something really unusual happens:

```rb
class TitleFetchError < StandardError
end

def get_title(url)
  request = HTTParty.get(url)

  Nokogiri::HTML(request.body).at_css('title').text

rescue HTTParty::Error => error
  raise TitleFetchError, error.to_s
rescue StandardError => error
  raise TitleFetchError, error.to_s
rescue ... (some other type of error, e.g. Nokogiri parse errors)
end
```

Where in my opinion that should actually be a method on the `@article` model, like `@article.fetch_title` which would do the same thing, using its own `link` property.

One thing to note is this pattern for writing controller actions helps simplify things:

```rb
def create
  @article = @user.articles.new(article_params)
  @article.title = get_title(@article.link)

  @article.save!
  redirect_to user_path, success: "Article Saved."

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved
  redirect_to user_path, danger: "Failed to save article."
rescue TitleFetchError => error
  redirect_to user_path, danger: "Failed to save article. Error: #{error}"
end
```

Where you have a nice clean "normal" path, and then your exceptions are handled on the side if/when that becomes necessary. This keeps the two flows separated and avoids additional nesting from the `if`.

Comment: This fails at the `request = HTTParty.get(url)` line if the `url` is bad and the request fails to open TCP connection. It never makes it to the rescue statement.

Comment: It throws some kind of exception, so you may need to determine exactly what kind is used, then `rescue` that specifically.

Comment: That's what I've done with the begin/rescue statement in my original question. But your answer doesn't help me understand how to pass an error message back to the `create` method. I don't want to display *that* it failed, I want to display *why* it failed. I assume I can include something with the `false` statement, but I don't know how/what.

Comment: I've added more to the example showing how you might re-wrap the exception in a form you can catch in your controller. This can be adapted in a number of ways.

Comment: One step closer. This does trigger `rescue TitleFetchError`, but in your example it only displays the static error message. How can I pass the error produced in the `get_title` method to the `create` method so I can display it in the flash? Everything I've tried keeps returning `undefined local variable or method`.

Comment: You can adapt it, re-wrap it, or whatever you want. The example there is with `#{e}` in the string, which you can get back with `e.to_s` if you capture the exception (`=>`) as `e`. If you want something more complicated, don't forget you can define `attr_accessor` type fields on your custom exceptions, then `raise CustomException.new(...)` with full control over what goes on.

Comment: I tried `flash.now[:danger] = e.to_s` but I'm still getting `undefined local variable or method`. Where would I call this `e.to_s`?

Comment: The general pattern is `rescue ExceptionType => e` where that creates a local variable `e` for that `rescue` block.

Comment: This is still not working. I followed the edits you made and nothing is happening on the page. In the terminal, the server output is showing `No template found for ArticlesController#create, rendering head :no_content`

Comment: You may want to `render(action: :new)` at the end of that if you don't have a create view.

Comment: I called `redirect_to` instead of trying to do a `flash.now`. I made a few edits relevant to this thread. Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate it.